# Secure a URL using AngularJS/Firebase/and S3

Tags: angularjs, amazon-s3, firebase

I'd like to host a webpage using an AWS S3 bucket (to store a video) that makes use of AngularJS and Firebase (for authentication). My requirement is a secure URL that a user can only go to once authenticated (e.g. /video). If I use AngularJS, anyone can read my Javascript and go to the URL directly so it's trivial to "hack." Is there a way that I can secure a URL using the above technologies?

Both of the following URLs would be accessible via AWS S3:

1. Main webpage is at site.com/ and of course defaults to index.html
2. Authenticated url is at site.com/video # you should only be able to get here once logged in

Answer (score 1):

You could store the location of the URL in firebase, say in a videos/ collection and require users to be authenticated in order to read from that collection. But this does not prevent other non-users from being about to find the URL to the video unless you implement server-side authentication.

Example:
Create an ec2 running Express or something, send a request to the ec2 with a one time token (stored in firebase, created by your App for authenticated users) unique to the authenticated user, set the headers of the response to successful and whatever MIME information you would need for the browser to recognize that the response is a video, then invalidate the token.

Comment: Thanks Connor, but I was trying to avoid a server side authentication scenario. I realize there may not be another way. Perhaps I can automate S3 bucket policies and restrict by a unique string (e.g. username)?